# Block timestamp

Tags: blockchain, blocks

```
Require(block.timestamp + 1 days - 1 hours <= numbers [14] ,
"Must lock longer than x") ;
Require(number [14] < 9999999999, "Avoid potential timestamp overflow");

Locktime = numbers[14];
Lockdiff = locktime.sub (block.timestamp)
```

How to read this code,what the function?
Thank.

Answer (score 2):

`require(condition, error_message)` is an error handling function that revert the transcation if the condition is not met.

```
require(block.timestamp + 1 days - 1 hours <= numbers [14] , "Must lock longer than x") ;
```

This line compare the block timestamp where the transaction is executed to a value stored in an array (here numbers[]), if the value `block.timestamp + 1 days - 1 hours` is less or equal to the value stored in `numbers [14]`, then the transaction is reverted.

```
require(number [14] < 9999999999, "Avoid potential timestamp overflow");
```

The other require limit the value of `number[]` (which it seems is different from the other array `numbers[]` to avoid a potential overflow which, before solidity v0.8.0, could often lead to security breach in smart contracts

```
Locktime = numbers[14]; 
Lockdiff = locktime.sub (block.timestamp)
```

Finally, the value of `block.timestamp` is subtracted to `locktime`
Here, the developer used the `sub` function from OpenZeppelin SafeMath library that was designed to avoid underflows
But for contract ^0.8.0 its not needed anymore